# Error creating SpatialPoints in sp package

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, r-sp

I am trying to convert a dataframe into a SpatialPoints and then save the coordinates in their correct CRS but am coming up with an error

```
proj_create: Error 1027 (Invalid value for an argument): utm: Invalid value for zone
Error in CRS("+proj=utm +zone=37N") : NA
```

This script worked fine before I updated my R & RStudio, and I am struggling to find the root of the problem. Any help would be appreciated

```
sps.37N <- SpatialPoints(dd3.full[,c("longitude", "latitude")], 
                         proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=37N"))
spst.37N  <- spTransform(sps.37N, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
dd3.full[, c("long", "lat")] <- coordinates(spst.37N)
```

Thanks

```
Sample data: structure(list(longitude = c(811674L, 811674L, 812382L, 811674L, 
812382L, 811674L, 807900L, 807900L, 812382L, 812405L), latitude = c(1061627L, 
1061627L, 1061168L, 1061627L, 1061168L, 1061627L, 1064949L, 1064949L, 
1061168L, 1061386L), site = c("DD City", "DD City", "DD City", 
"DD City", "DD City", "DD City", "DD City", "DD City", "DD City", 
"DD City"), idindividual = c("DDIC-001-C1-F01", "DDIC-001-C1-F02", 
"DDIC-001-C1-F03", "DDIC-001-C1-F04", "DDIC-001-C1-F05", "DDIC-001-C1-F06", 
"DDIC-001-C2-F01", "DDIC-001-C2-F02", "DDIC-001-C2-F03", "DDIC-001-C3-F01"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what does `rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion()` show you?

Comment: @Chris GDAL:     "3.5.2"        GDAL_with_GEOS : "TRUE"    PROJ:   "8.2.1"   sp: "1.5-1"

Comment: A proposed [workaround](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387072/r-spcrs-returns-na) without the satisfaction of 'getting to the root cause'. And you might edit your above to place the error where it was triggered, for future readers, as context is helpful.

Comment: I confirm your error msg, and workaround appears to work `wkt1 <- sf::st_crs(32637)[[2]] ` #epsg for utm 37N, `sps.37N <- SpatialPoints(dd3.full[, c('longitude', 'latitude')], sp::CRS(wkt1))`, transform warns, `spst.37N  <- spTransform(sps.37N, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
Warning message:
PROJ support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others`, then `dd3.full[, c("long", "lat")] <- coordinates(spst.37N)` without complaint. You might prefer starting in `sf`.